# String or binary data would be truncated, even though the string is shorter than column length

Tags: sql-server

I had a table with a column which is a `VARCHAR(4)`. In SQL Server (Right-click > Design) I changed this to `VARCHAR(10)`.

Now when I try to update the the value from AAAA to BBBBBB it gives me the error message:

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

Is there anything else than the column's length in `VARCHAR(10)` that might be causing this error?

Comment: Ss it NVARCHAR or are you sure its varchar(4)?

Comment: Check if there are triggers and/or CHECK constraints (using user defined functions).

Comment: Does an `insert` work with the longer string?

Comment: Check to make sure you are referencing the correct table. In the designer maybe you altered a different table then you are referencing in your script or maybe pointing to a different database with similar schema. In your script you can use `sp_columns TABLENAME` to double check.

Comment: Would you have to commit on a field change like that?

Comment: Just check you can manually add specified text in table column

Comment: Do you have a trigger on the table?

Answer (score 0):

Some things you need to confirm.

- Is the column actually resized (does it register as varchar(10)) ?
- Are you updating the correct table ?
- Are you updating in the correct database ?
- Check in profiler the update command that is send to the database, maybe your client does something to it ?
- Are there any other string fields in your update, maybe one of them is too long ?
- Are you updating the correct field with BBBBBB ?